How to subclass mpmath's mpf?
I'd like to extend mpmath's (https://mpmath.org/) number type mpf in my own class, but it does not seem to be possible to use it as a base class in the usual way.
With
import mpmath
class A(mpmath.mpf):
    def __init__(self, v):
        super().__init__(v)

you get
>>> A(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

After a look into mpmath's (pretty complex) python sources I am aware that mpmath.mpf is not constructed like a "normal" Python class. Is it anyway somehow possible to properly inherit from it?

You're right, the argument self was wrong here. I edited the question, but it does not change the error message.

I'd assume that mpmath.mpf construct the object using __new__, but not __init__, that's why object.__init__ is called on calling super().__init__.
So, you don't really have to call parent __init__. Just save the value if you need it.
class A(mpmath.mpf):
    def __init__(self, value: float):
        self.value = value

But for your purposes, I think this would be better:
class A:
    def __init__(self, value: float):
        self.value = value
        self.mpf = mpmath.mpf(value)

    def __add__(self, other: "A") -> "A":
        return A(value=self.value + other.value)


(A(1)+A(2)).value -> AttributeError: 'mpf' object has no attribute 'value' and
type(A(1)+A(2)) -> <class 'mpmath.ctx_mp_python.mpf'>
That does not do the trick, unfortunately.

Yes, you have to override __add__ method to be able to sum your objects. See updated answer, I think I found better solution for you.

The whole point of using mpmath.mp as base class is that it already implements all arithmetic functions, which are quite a lot. Your suggestion implies that I have to provide them by myself, which I aim to avoid.
